# Attaching type hints to a Clojure delayed call

Tags: clojure

I'm attempting to put handles on Java objects which aren't available at compile time, but are available at runtime, in vars as follows:

```
(def component-manager (delay (SomeJavaObject/getHandle)))
```

(If a better mechanism than delays is available, this would be welcome).

When these objects are used, a reflection warning is generated. As sometimes these are fairly frequent, I've tried to avoid it with the following:

```
(def my-handle ^SomeJavaObject (delay (SomeJavaObject/getHandle)))
```

Unfortunately, the reflection warning is still generated in this case.

---

Modifying the references works:

```
(.foo ^SomeJavaObject @my-handle)
```

...but this uglifies the code substantially.

---

Wrapping in a macro which adds the type hints seems an obvious approach:

```
(def my-handle' (delay (SomeJavaObject/getHandle)))
(defmacro my-handle []
  (with-meta '(deref my-handle')
             {:tag SomeJavaObject}))
```

...and looks like it should do the right thing:

```
=> (set! *print-meta* true)
=> (macroexpand '(my-handle))
^SomeJavaObject (deref my-handle')
```

...but this doesn't hold true when the rubber hits the road:

```
=> (.foo (my-handle))
Reflection warning, NO_SOURCE_PATH:1 - reference to field foo can't be resolved.
```

---

What's the right way to do this?

Comment: `(def my-handle ^SomeJavaObject (delay (SomeJavaObject/getHandle)))` is incorrect because you are trying to type hint the result of `delay`. That doesn't make sense, because it already has the type `clojure.lang.Delay`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd like to offer two different solutions:

**1. delay**

First off, I wanted to post an answer that shows how your problem can be recreated. (As worded, your question is abstract and cannot be run in a REPL.)

```
(set! *warn-on-reflection* true)
(def rt (delay (Runtime/getRuntime)))
(.availableProcessors @rt) ; Reflection warning
```

You mention that you don't like the following approach because you consider it verbose:

```
(.availableProcessors ^java.lang.Runtime @rt) ; no warning
```

I tried the following, but it did not solve the reflection warning:

```
(def rt (delay ^java.lang.Runtime (Runtime/getRuntime)))
(.availableProcessors @rt) ; Reflection warning
```

Conclusion: if you want to use a delay, [Ankur's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10891567/109618) works great. To adapt it to this example:

```
(def delayed-runtime (delay (Runtime/getRuntime)))
(defn ^java.lang.Runtime get-runtime [] @delayed-runtime)
(.availableProcessors (get-runtime)) ; no warning
```

**2. memoize**

You might also consider using memoization, as it requires less code:

```
(def ^java.lang.Runtime get-runtime (memoize #(Runtime/getRuntime)))
(.availableProcessors (get-runtime)) ; no warning
```

Comment: I should have said the above is just an example; I'm not necessarily suggesting that you would want to memoize the `getRuntime` call, above. (I'd need to read more to see if the JVM only keeps a singleton of that anyway.)

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if delay is the best thing here or there can be much better solution for managing those Java objects, but as far as reflection warning is concerned below code does solve it by wrapping the delay value access in a function with type hint.

```
user=> (set! *warn-on-reflection* true)
true
user=> (def myobj (delay "hello world"))
#'user/myobj
user=> (defn ^String get-my-obj [] @myobj)
#'user/get-my-obj
user=> (.length (get-my-obj))
11
```

To make it much more easier you can create a macro that creates the delay object and also create a `get-<delay object name>` function to access that delay object by using type hint.